# Postgres, I am getting ERROR: unexpected chunk number 0 (expected 1) for toast value 12599063 in pg_toast_16687

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres and one of my reports that is using select and extracting JSON return the following error.

```
ERROR:  unexpected chunk number 0 (expected 1) for toast value 12599063 in pg_toast_16687
SQL state: XX000
```

I do not know how to proceed in fixing my query. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Run this command:

```
select reltoastrelid::regclass from pg_class where relname = 'table_name';
```

Where the table_name is where the error occur. Then check the result if it is the same toast# like  pg_toast.pg_toast_XXXXX. Mine happen to be 16687

Then run these commands to reindex:

```
REINDEX table table_name;
REINDEX table pg_toast.pg_toast_16687;
VACUUM analyze table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is data corruption:

- restore from backup
- upgrade to the latest PostgreSQL minor release
- check the hardware

Comment: The issue was solved by taking a dump from the corrupted database and restoring it.